# Mutt Forwarding with Attachment - Macros for tagging all attachments

Tags: mutt

I am trying to do a macros to forward an email with its attachments. The macros should do these steps:
1 - Open attachments
2 - Tag all attachments
3 - Forward (;f)

I am trying to do it using this macro:

`macro index,pager "F" "<view-attachments>ttttttttt;f"`

But if the number of attachments is odd it doesn't tag the last one (every time you press "t" it tags but if it is already tagged it untags it). How to tag all of them?

Answer (score 2):

mutt and neomutt has config option [forward_attachments](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#forward-attachments). Attachments will or won't be forwarded based on this settings. Or you will be asked with default yes/no preset.

There's no need for creating macro for this. Or is it?

Comment: The  `forward_attachment` option was added to mutt 1.12, which was released on 25/05/2019 [1]. It found its way into neomutt with the release 2019-10-25 [2].
For older versions, as eg. shipped with some long-term-support linux distribuitons, a macro that automates the workarounds listed in [1] might be desireable.

[1]: http://www.mutt.org/relnotes/1.12/
[2]: https://neomutt.org/2019/10/25/release